# Which commands to use to extract and reconstruct multivolume archives using .rev files on CentOS 6.x?

Tags: centos, rar

Which commands can be used to extract & reconstruct multivolume RAR archives with missing parts using .rev files in Centos 6.x?

I have many RAR archives split into many parts:

```
dbzdv1
   part01.rar
   part02.rar
   part03.rar
...
dbzdv2
   part01.rar
   part02.rar
   part03.rar
...
```

[Screenshot of files of a multivolume archive http://imageshack.com/a/img633/5450/ekUKTd.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img633/5450/ekUKTd.png)

All volumes are protected with same password.

**1. I want extract with a single command all protected multivolume RAR archives**

Every RAR archive is split into many parts.

**2. The .rev file should be used to automatically reconstruct a missing part.**

**3. I shoud have folders with files inside after extraction.**

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

*I want compress with RAR with a single command all those folders into separate archives:*

```
folder1.rar
folder2.rar
folder3.rar
```

**4. I want get a multivolume RAR archive with no compression and automatically tested on errors if an extracted folder is very large.**

```
folder1 --> folder1.part01.rar
            folder2.part02.rar
```

Problems:

If I try using this command to extract a volume:

```
unrar e dbzdv1.part01.rar
```

Shortly after start in terminal I'm asked for password *for every part*, not just once for the entire multivolume archive. I don't want to type password for 100-500 parts.

[image: Screenshot of terminal window]

If I try using WinRAR on Wine and open files the error `Not enough memory` is output.

[Screenshot of files of winrar-wine error http://imageshack.com/a/img913/2331/n6LOtl.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img913/2331/n6LOtl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

I'm not using CentOS and therefore all my answers are not verified on this operating system.

**WinRAR** is installed usually on Windows with 3 executables:

- GUI version `WinRAR.exe` supporting compression in RAR and ZIP format and even more common archive formats for extraction (shareware).
- Console version `Rar.exe` supporting compression and extraction of RAR archives only (shareware).
- Console application `UnRAR.exe` for extraction of RAR archives only (free, no license needed).

In program files folder of **WinRAR** there is additionally the text file `Rar.txt` which is the manual for the console version `Rar`. GUI Version `WinRAR` supports nearly same set of switches, but there are some differences like `-af<type>` supported only by GUI version. The complete list of switches for `WinRAR` can be found in help on page *Alphabetic switches list* (Contents - Command line mode - Switches). `Rar` and `UnRAR` output both a short help with listing all supported commands and switches if executed in a command prompt window without any parameter.

---

### Extraction from several password protected multivolume archives

The switch `-p[pwd]` can be used on command line to extract files from a password protected archive of any type as explained for example in `Rar.txt`.

Examples:

```
UnRAR.exe x -pPasswordOfArchive MyArchive.rar
UnRAR.exe x "-p!Password Of Archive!" MyArchive.rar
```

This switch with the password must be enclosed in double quotes if the password contains 1 or more spaces or other special characters according to the requirements for command line strings of the script interpreter (`cmd.exe` on Windows, bash or sh on Linux).

Only the first file of a multivolume archive must be specified on command line to extract all files and folders from all volumes (parts) of an archive.

Example:

```
UnRAR.exe x -pMyPassword MyMultiVolumeArchive.part1.rar
```

The other files (parts) of `MyMultiVolumeArchive` must be in same directory as first file and all parts must be present and valid.

The manual `Rar.txt` contains for command `rv` the paragraph:

> RAR reconstructs missing and damaged volumes either when using `rc` command or automatically, if it cannot locate the next volume and finds the required number of .rev files when unpacking.

I tested the statement about automatically using *.rev files and it is not 100% true for v5.10 on Windows on extraction for multivolume RAR archives independent on which executable is used and if the multivolume RAR4 archive is password protected, completely encrypted or not protected. A missing part is automatically reconstructed using the recovery volumes, but not a damaged part resulting in one or more checksum errors on extraction of files. It is necessary to run a reconstruct on a multivolume RAR archive with a damaged volume before extraction can be done for all files and folders successfully.

The manual `Rar.txt` contains near top in chapter about *RAR command line syntax* the paragraph:

> Many RAR commands, such as extraction, test or list, allow to use wildcards in archive name. If no extension is specified in archive mask, RAR assumes `.rar`, so `*` means all archives with `.rar`  extension. If you need to process all archives without extension, use `*.` mask. `*.*` mask selects all files. Wildcards in archive name are not allowed when archiving and deleting.

So extraction of all files and folders from all password protected multivolume RAR archives in same directory is very easy:

```
UnRAR.exe x -idcdp -pCommonPassword *.rar
```

`UnRAR` automatically detects all *.rar files in the directory independent on type (single or multivolume archive) and decompresses them all whereby nothing is extracted twice. So after extraction of `MyMultiVolumeArchive.part1.rar` it continues automatically on part 2, 3, ... and after processing this multivolume archive, continues with next archive with a different file name in same directory.

It might be useful to use additionally the switch `-ad` to extract all files and folders of an archive to a folder with name of archive file to avoid extraction of files from different archives into same directory.

Example:

```
UnRAR.exe x -idcdp -ad -pCommonPassword *.rar
```

But take into account that the created folder contains also `.part*1` in name for a multivolume archive. So using this switch on multivolume archives does not produce nice looking folder names.

On Windows the following command can be used to remove `.part*1` from all folder names:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %D in ( `dir *part* /AD /B /ON` ) do ren "%D" "%~nD"
```

As batch file:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%D in ( `dir *part* /AD /B /ON` ) do ren "%%D" "%%~nD"
```

It is not possible to specify several RAR archives on a command line without usage of wildcards.

A command line like

```
UnRAR x -pArchivePassword FirstArchive.part1.rar SecondArchive.part001.rar ThirdArchive.rar
```

would be interpreted as order to extract the files `SecondArchive.part001.rar` and `ThirdArchive.rar` from multivolume archive `FirstArchive`.

---

### Reconstruct several password protected multivolume archives

The command `rc` must be used instead of `x` to reconstruct a multivolume archive using recovery volumes (*.rev).

This command is not supported by `UnRAR`, only by `Rar` and `WinRAR`.

It is not possible to reconstruct all multivolume RAR archives in a directory with a single command. If a wildcard like `*.rar` is used with command `rc`, just the first RAR archive matching the file mask will be processed for checking archive integrity and reconstruct a volume if damaged or missing.

Therefore a command line respectively shell script (*.bat, *.sh) is required to run RAR with command `rc` on all multivolume archives in a directory.

But it is not necessary to first test archive integrity on each multivolume archive using command `t` as archives with no damaged or missing volume are not modified at all on reconstruct.

Example for a single archive:

```
Rar.exe rc -pArchivePassword MyMultiVolumeArchive.part001.rar
```

Here is a Windows batch file for that task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in ( `dir *part*1.rar /A-D /B /ON` ) do (

    rem Get string of archive file name after first dot which should be
    rem the dot before part*1 as otherwise this procedure would produce
    rem a wrong result. In other words this procedure does not work with
    rem archive file names containing an additional dot before .part*.rar.

    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%M in ( "%%~nF" ) do (
       set PartNumber=%%N
       rem Remove all zeros from "part*1"
       set PartNumber=!PartNumber:0=!
       rem Remove also "part" from "part*1".
       set PartNumber=!PartNumber:part=!
       rem Check if part number is 1 and not 11 or 101 or 111.
       if "!PartNumber!" == "1" (
          echo.
          echo Reconstruct archive %%M
          "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" rc -idcd -pArchivePassword "%%F"
       )
    )
)
endlocal
```

---

### Create a RAR archive for each subdirectory in a directory

`WinRAR` has after pressing button **Add** in toolbar the option *Put each file to separate archive* on tab *Files* explained in help opened by pressing button **Help**. `WinRAR` creates for each selected folder and selected file in root of the current directory a separate archive with name of folder / file.

But this is a feature supported by `WinRAR` only on using GUI. It is not supported on command line as far as I know whether by `WinRAR` nor by `Rar`.

Therefore it is necessary to run a small command line / shell script (*.bat, *.sh) to compress each folder in a directory into a separate archive. Just a single line is necessary to achieve that at least on Windows.

Windows command line:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %D in ( `dir /AD /B /ON` ) do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -t -v10M "%D.rar" "%D"
```

Windows batch file:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%D in ( `dir /AD /B /ON` ) do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r-t -v10M "%%D.rar" "%%D"
```

The example compresses each folder recursively to an archive with same name using best compression, omitting the path to the folder in archive and creating a multivolume archive with 10 MB per volume. The created archives are additionally tested for integrity although this is usually not needed.